# How to disable the Wordpress posts access from date paths?

Tags: wordpress

My posts are accessible by anyone that uses the url of my website + a date path.

How can I disable this feature, so that the only way to access my posts are using the slug?

Example - https://www.carreirafinance.com/goals-to-set/

My current setup for Settings -> Permalinks -> Common Settings -> Post name

I am trying to disable the fact that when someone goes to my website, she/he can access articles using a date in the url.

Example - https://www.carreirafinance.com/2021/01/19/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple plugin which can disable listing posts by date. just upload it to your `wp-content/plugins`, and enable it at admin portal.

`disable-date-path.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Disable date path
 * Description: Disable date path
 * Author:      Emptyhua
 * Version:     0.1
 */

if (!function_exists('my_disable_date_path')) {
    function my_disable_date_path($query) {
        if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_date) {
            wp_die('Date path disabled.');
        }
    }

    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_disable_date_path');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Login to WordPress admin.

Go to `Settings` => `Permalink` => `Common Settings` and then select option **Post name**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it is already setup that way. That is why I can access my post using the slug. What I am trying to do is blocking the fact that I can also access it using a date.